# VS 2008, .net 3.5 project in VS 2010: Could not load type ...EntityDesignerBuildProvider

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to move a project from VS 2008 to VS 2010. The project upgrade wizard completed fine, but the project does not compile. It says:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config(129):
>   error ASPCONFIG: Could not load type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider'.

I have chosen to stay with .net 3.5, but from this error it seems like it is linking to version 4 of framework. If I right click on the solution and choose Properties, the Target framework on the Application tab is set to .NET 3.5

I have VS 2008 installed on the same computer, and the project compiles and runs fine.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What type of project is this.  Windows Form?  Web App?

Comment: It's a web app (ASP.net, C#, MVC2)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762256/mvcbuildviews-true-with-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-2

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you have this in to your web.config.

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You are using 4.0 version of the libraries, and you have set targetFramework to 4.0. I am targetting 3.5: is this still true?