# MVC3 razor Error in creating HtmlButtonExtension

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to create a custom html button  on my page using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955571/theres-no-html-button)

```
public static class HtmlButtonExtension 
{
  public static MvcHtmlString Button(this HtmlHelper helper, string text,
                                     IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
  {
      var builder = new TagBuilder("button");
      builder.InnerHtml = text;
      builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
      return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
  }
}
```

When I click this button I want to pass an recordID to my Action

Given below is what I added to my razor view

@Html.Button("Delete", new {name="CustomButton", recordID ="1" })

But I could not get to display this button,and it's throwing erros

```
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<wmyWebRole.ViewModels.MyViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Button' and the best extension method overload 'JSONServiceRole.Utilities.HtmlButtonExtension.Button(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object>)' has some invalid arguments
```

Can some one help me to identify the actual error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing an anonymous object, not an `IDictionary<string, object>` for `htmlAttributes`.

You can add an additional overload with `object htmlAttributes`. This is how they do it in the built-in ASP.NET MVC Html Helpers:

```
public static class HtmlButtonExtension 
{    
  public static MvcHtmlString Button(this HtmlHelper helper, string text,
                                     object htmlAttributes)
  {
      return Button(helper, text, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
  }

  public static MvcHtmlString Button(this HtmlHelper helper, string text,
                                     IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
  {
      var builder = new TagBuilder("button");
      builder.InnerHtml = text;
      builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
      return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
  }

}
```