# Pass tuple with two object collections to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, tuples

I want to pass two collections of objects. First is `Post`, second is `Gallery`. However I get error and I don't know how to fix this.

I've done this when passing two single objects and it is working fine, but now I need to pass two collections of those objects and it gives me error.

Error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Tuple`2[System.Linq.IQueryable`1[photoBlog.Models.Gallery],System.Linq.IQueryable`1[photoBlog.Models.Post]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Tuple`2[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[photoBlog.Models.Gallery],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[photoBlog.Models.Post]]'.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    photoBlogModelDataContext _db = new photoBlogModelDataContext();
    var posts = _db.Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).Take(4);
    var galleries = _db.Galleries.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(4);
    return View(Tuple.Create(galleries, posts));
}
```

View

```
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<photoBlog.Models.Gallery>, IEnumerable<photoBlog.Models.Post>>
@foreach (var item in Model.Item1)
{
   @item.Name
}
```

Comment: What error do you get, and at what point?

Comment: When I try to loop trough `Model.Item1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should modify your controller method to this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    photoBlogModelDataContext _db = new photoBlogModelDataContext();
    var posts = _db.Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).Take(4).ToArray();
    var galleries = _db.Galleries.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(4).ToArray();
    return View(Tuple.Create(galleries, posts));
}
```

From your error message, it appears that the queries are not resolved yet when your view is rendered. By also doing ToArray or ToList, you will force the query to hit the database before you return from the controller method.

Comment: This working provided that I changed my view to `@model Tuple<photoBlog.Models.Gallery[], photoBlog.Models.Post[]>`

Comment: @stan if you don't want to change view then just change in controller from above example. Use .ToList() in place of .ToArray()

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new Entity in your domain.Model

Here is an example I provided today :
[MVC3: button to send both form (model) values and an extra parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829541/mvc3-button-to-send-both-form-model-values-and-an-extra-parameter/10829908#10829908)

Later Edit :

```
namespace App.Domain.Model
{
    public class Tuple
    {
        public IEnumerable<photoBlog.Models.Gallery> Gallery{ get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<photoBlog.Models.Post> Post{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

you will send the Tuple object to your view as follows :

```
@model: (Domain.Model.)Tuple  <--- (your exact model path )
@foreach (var item in Model.Gallery)
{
   @item.Name
}
```

Another posibility would be using viewbag ... but i strongly suggest you do it the correct way,i.e. the MVC way

Comment: I hope that this is not the only option. Would rather do it with tuples w/o modifying my model.

Comment: you are not modifying your model ... I will make a small explination as edit in 2 mins .. so you understanbd the process

Comment: Okey, I made it with Tuples. Is this way somehow better or more MVC-Standart like?

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you cannot send to the model 2 Entities. Thus you create an Entity that holds 2 entities. Basically you can pass to your view any type of data (int string entity listof entity) with no problems.P.S. I would suggest you transform your Ienumerables into Lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
var posts = _db.Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).Take(4).ToList();
var galleries = _db.Galleries.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(4).ToList();
```