# How can I unit test views in an MVC3 application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I recently had a slip up where, during a demo, navigation to a view failed because the view still referenced a property that I had removed from the view model.

The application still has very little logic, except mapping between domain model and view model, and I would like to introduce unit tests now, and proceed with a more TDD oriented approach, but this case has me stumped? How can I write a unit test that mocks a view?

Comment: Do you have `MvcBuildViews` element set to `True` in your MVC .proj file? This will compile the views as part of the build and *should* detect these kinds of problems

Comment: The compiler should give you a warning if you reference a property that a class doesn't have. For example if you invoke `@model WebUI.Models.PersonModel` -> `<p>@Model.SomeNonExistantProperty</p>`, the compiler should warn you about this. Now if this manifest in a red squiggly but no build time compiler error, someone please tell me. :)

Comment: Thanks @Russ. It's worth that I also needed to modify my web.config to get this to work, as advised in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762256/mvcbuildviews-true-with-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [WatiN](http://watin.org/) in the past for just that, however it looks like it might not be maintained anymore.  The last update update was back in April (10 months ago).