# could not load type 'system.data.entity.design.aspnet.entitydesignerbuildprovider'

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

```
<add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
```

this is the Assembly of my System Web.config file

Comment: please revert me back

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762256/mvcbuildviews-true-with-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-2

Answer (score 51):

Open your web.config and add this line below in the Assemblies section:

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
```

For more information, check this link:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1698282.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, checkout @GregoryBrad's answer below.

Answer (score 24):

Adding to @wandos answer, here is the layout for web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```