# compile time error checking in views in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

How to enable compile time error checking  of views in visual studio 2012 (MVC application using entityframework)
I have tried this

```
  <MvcBuildViews>  true </MvcBuildViews>
```

Error is :
 Error77 Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider'.

Comment: possible duplicate question: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/17833753/1798775][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17833753/1798775

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a reference to `System.Data.Entity.Design`. Try the solution found [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1698282.aspx?Error%20Could%20not%20load%20type%20System%20Data%20Entity%20Design%20AspNet%20EntityDesignerBuildProvider%20)

Add

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
```

In your web.config file