# Amend Azure DevOps Web Config

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops

How can I access and amend Azure DevOps Pipelines machine config (web.config)?

We actually encountered the same problem listed in [could not load type 'system.data.entity.design.aspnet.entitydesignerbuildprovider'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833753/could-not-load-type-system-data-entity-design-aspnet-entitydesignerbuildprovide), however that can easily be solved by amending our local machine's web.config.

But we now face the same problem on Azure DevOps Pipelines. How then can we access the same file on the Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access and amend Azure DevOps Pipelines machine config (web.config)?

If you're using the Microsoft-provided hosted agent, you could not access and amend Azure DevOps Pipelines machine config. Because we could not access the hosted agent with an administrator account.

The workaround for this issue, you can set up your self-hosted private agent, then access and amend machine config on the local machine where the private agent is deployed.

Hope this helps.